# req.file is undefined when trying to post form information

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am having a problem with my file upload. I have a form that send data to my controller in my routes file. When the data is posted the req.file is undefinded. What im trying to do is send the image to my public/images and then put the image name into my candidates.

here is my form

```
<div class="page-wrap text-center">
<div ng-controller = "candidatesController">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class=" col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form class = "content-margin" ng-submit="addCandidate()" style="margin-top:30px" enctype   =  "multipart/form-data">
                <h3 class = "formheading"> Add a new Candidate</h3>

                <div class = "form-group" align = "center">
                    <input type = "string" class = "form-control" placeholder = "candidate name" ng-model = "formData.name" ng-style = "{'width':150 + 'px'}"></input>
                </div>
                <div class = "form-group" align = "center">
                    <input type = "string" class = "form-control" placeholder = "candidate role" ng-model = "formData.role" ng-style = "{'width':150 + 'px'}"></input>
                </div>
                <div class = "form-group" align = "center">
                    <input type = "string" class = "form-control" placeholder = "candidate email" ng-model = "formData.email" ng-style = "{'width':150 + 'px'}"></input>
                </div>
                <input method    =  "post" type="file" name="userPhoto" nd-model = "file"/>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Candidate</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is my controller

```
router.addPerson = function(req, res) {

    console.warn(req.files);



    var candidate = new CandidateModel();

    candidate.name = req.body.name;
    console.warn(req.body.name);
    candidate.role = req.body.role;
    console.warn(req.body.role);
    candidate.email = req.body.email;
    console.warn(req.body.email);
    console.warn(candidateImage);


    // Save the donation and check for errors
    candidate.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Donation Added!', data: candidate });
    });

}
```

I dont have the file upload code done yet as I cant even get the file to be sent over. Here is the function in my controller.

```
$scope.updateCandidate = function(){

    $scope.formData.id = candidateId.getID();

    $http.post('/candidates/'+ candidateId.getID(), $scope.formData)
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.candidates = data;
            $location.path('/candidates');
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error:' + data);
        });
}
```

any help would be great

Comment: What file upload middleware are you using? Multer, busboy? Maybe something custom?

Comment: I am using multer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your angular code, you're not setting the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data`. By default `$http.post()` sends requests using `application/json`

```
return $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/candidates/' + candidateId.getId(),
  data: $scope.formData,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/formadata'
  }
})
  .then((data) => {
    // handle data
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle error 
  });
```